# How 'expert' do my questions need to be for this site?

Tags: discussion

I'm just starting out on DSP and most of my knowledge is self-taught and researched online.  As I'm learning I may have some pretty basic questions for this site.  For example, I had/have a question related to clarify how what certain Modulation Schemes are and how they work.  Would questions of a more basic nature be on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any level of question is welcome.

Comment: Agreed with datageist: Ask as clear and precise a question as you can. Level doesn't matter.

Comment: This is very good to hear/read. Signal Processing is all very new to me (I know the Physics of some of it) - it is proving to be an interesting field.